# Jquery Array, Append and Mouseover problems

Tags: jquery, arrays, append, mouseover

i am basically working on a slide show,  once user click on the navigation accordingly, the array elements will show up for that given button.

```
        var modules ={};
    modules[0] = new Array();
    modules[0][0] ="content 1 - 0";
    modules[0][1] ="content 1 - 1";
    modules[0][2] ="content 1 - 2";
    modules[0][3] ="content 1 - 3";

    modules[1] = new Array();
    modules[1][0] ="content 2 - 0";
    modules[1][1] ="content 2 - 1";
    modules[1][2] ="content 2 - 2";
    modules[1][3] ="content 2 - 3";
    modules[1][4] ="content 2 - 4";

        $(".container").mouseover(function(){
            var number = $(".container").index(this);
            jQuery.each(modules[number], function(index,value){
                $(".details").eq(0).append("<div class='details-word'>" + value + '</div>');
            })
        });


})
```

i use number to track which button user mouseover, and each array will wrap with details-word div. with this code, the details container keep getting repeat content from the array. i guess something is wrong with my code, but don't know how to fix it...

i am still new with jquery, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

solved, i use hover instead of mouseover, and use .remove() to remove append.